# How can I open the default SMS inbox activity programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, inbox

I want to open the default sms inbox in Android on click of a button in my application. I don't want to create my own activity to display inbox messages. I have searched a lot of links but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: Intent eventIntentMessage =getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(getApplicationContext));
startActivity(eventIntentMessage);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this question: [launch sms application with an intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372248/launch-sms-application-with-an-intent). There are a number of responses that you can try.

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList");
```