# Allowing my app to send a file to another device via MMS/Email

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing an app and one thing I would like to do it allow users to send/share data from the app with others vi MMS or by email. I have been searching but haven't found anywhere to get started on solving the problem.

Basically, I am going to programatically draw the data from an SQLite DB and put it into a delimited file (similar to a .csv) then I want to allow the user to 'export' or send it via MMS or Email. Does anyone have any tips on how I can get my program to open the messaging application and add the attachment at the users direction? Really just need some beginning info so I have a place to start.

Comment: James, this is basically duplicated in numerous other places. Do a search for "android email intent attachments". One of the first in Google is: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html. Give the file attachment your own file extension. Then register an intent filter saying that your app handles that extension so the receiver can open it in your app. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: Thanks Erik! Must have been some poor search syntax on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for. This should be a good start

[launch sms application with an intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372248/launch-sms-application-with-an-intent)

Comment: Awesome! Just the thing I was looking for. Thanks!