# How to open android SMS app from my app and locate to a message

Tags: android

I'm writing an android app which have one function of searching the SMS content. After getting the result, if user clicks the one item, I want to open other SMS app to view details

Then I use code from link [launch sms application with an intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372248/launch-sms-application-with-an-intent/4826171#4826171)

My question is, seems the code from above only open the conversation, and locate me to the latest message.

How to open one exact message? I mean navigate user to correct location of the conversation, not always the end.
Can I provide id or other informations to Intent?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the source code I found the solution.

Before transfer to other Intent, put extra infomation thread_id and select_id(the _id property of the sms). Code is:

```
    smsIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");

    smsIntent.putExtra("thread_id",Long.valueOf(threadIdView.getText().toString()));
    smsIntent.putExtra("select_id",Long.valueOf(idView.getText().toString()));
```