# Android: showing blank screen after backing from intent

Tags: android, android-intent

What I want to do is pretty simple. I want app to launch sms app with pre-writen recipient. I made a new  Android Application Project and used this [code to lauch sms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372248/launch-sms-application-with-an-intent). It works perfectly until I hit back button. It closes the sms app and then shows a blank screen [image].

My code looks like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    smsIntent.putExtra("address", "0123456789");
    startActivity(smsIntent);
}
```

I thought it has something to do with a layout and it starts a blank activity (?) at the start of the app so i tried to comment out the setting of a layout `//setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`. It didn't help.

I also tried to override `onBackPressed()` which also didn't help.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    finish();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Is it possible to disable showing of the blank screen ?

Comment: do you want to show the blank screen or not ? if yes then what exactly you want to have on this screen ?

Comment: Do you know that `System.exit(0);` is probably the worst thing you can do to your app? It will screw everything up and I mean EVERYTHING. Android doesn't work like a normal java application. You as a developer do not control the the lifecycle of anything. Just call `finish();` and the OS will take care of the rest. This `System.exit(0);` call may just be the cause of your problems in the first place.

Comment: @Darkie I don't want to show that blank screen at all.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Ye I read about that, but I was just trying things in hope to solve my problem, so I also tried that.

Comment: have you checked my answer @Broxe

Comment: @Broxe just add finish(); like the answer below and I think you got it right now cheers :)

Comment: @maven Yes and I also tried it out, but Burak's solution seems a bit easier. Anyway thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    smsIntent.putExtra("address", "0123456789");
    startActivity(smsIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works just as I want. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

use this theme in the activity

add this style in your  `style.xml`

```
<style name="aAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Wallpaper">
    <item name="android:background">@color/Black</item>
</style>
```

add this line to the manifest `manifest.xml`

```
<activity
android:name="yourpackagename.activityname"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/aAppTheme" 
>
```

regards 
maven