# Share text with SMS on Samsung Galaxy S5

Tags: android

I am trying to share text through SMS. It looks fine on most of the phones, even Samsung phones, except on Galaxy S5.

Here is the code:

```
public static void shareWithSMS(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable String text) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", "", null));
    intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", text);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

It launch the app for SMS, without any text.
Does anyone know why?

**UPDATE**

The aim is to launch the sms app of the device, not to send the SMS. That's why I am not using `SmsManager`.

Comment: Does the Galaxy S5 has a different/non-standard SMS Provider? Maybe that is the question...

Comment: Yes that's my thought too. I google it but I could't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You have Two method to do so.one of them is using `smsManager()`and other one is Using `Intent`
So use this Code For Send Message:

```
    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", getString(R.string.social_invitation));
            startActivity(smsIntent);
```

Enjoy Your Code:)

Comment: Hey Piyush Gupta. So, I removed the URI but still same problem :( And about the first solution, I don't want to send the sms from my app, but open the default sms app of the user.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same trouble. I found solution here [launch sms application with an intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372248/launch-sms-application-with-an-intent)

If android version is Kitkat or above, users can change default sms application. This method will get default sms app and start default sms app.

```
private void sendSMS() {    
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) // At least KitKat
      {
         String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this); // Need to change the build to API 19

         Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
         sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");

         if (defaultSmsPackageName != null)// Can be null in case that there is no default, then the user would be able to choose
         // any app that support this intent.
         {
            sendIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
         }
         startActivity(sendIntent);

      }
      else // For early versions, do what worked for you before.
      {
         Intent smsIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
         smsIntent.putExtra("address","phoneNumber");         
         smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","message");
         startActivity(smsIntent);
      }
   }
```