# Correctly implement SMS intent receiver

Tags: android, android-intent

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372248/launch-sms-application-with-an-intent) the user wants to launch an sms app by an `Intent`.

I'm trying to set my app to receive this request in order to appear in the selectable apps to send an sms.

The app already works well, I'm only missing this part.

I've tried some of the answers from the said thread to test if what I did was working but unfortunately none works.

In my manifest I set this to my conversation activity.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Any kind of help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.