# Android deep link to message app

Tags: android, html, css, deep-linking, deeplink

When I open a link to an android device, should open message app with a phone number and some content.

How I can do it,I know that I need use a deep link,but can you help me?
I already do it for ios device but I can't do it  for android.

code for IOS :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout('Redirect()',10);
        function Redirect()
        {
             location.href = 'sms:1-408-555-1212&body=VASKA SMURFIC';
        }
</script>
```

I try using deep ling, but i can't find example for message app

Thank you)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [launch sms application with an intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372248/launch-sms-application-with-an-intent)

Comment: http://api.ayomobile.com/mconnect/sueno/web_in/?telcoID=1&msg=REG%20SDS this is example work with android. I want include this code in html file,as i do with ios redirect example

Comment: I think you need to drop the quotes `'` around your function call, try this: `setTimeout(Redirect(), 10);`