# How to open sms app via implicit intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I follow this code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    startActivity(intent);
```

It work up to android 5.1, but doesn't work android 6.0, because `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent`. So, how to open sms app via implicit intent?

**EDIT:**

1. You read my post? I need open app, not send message.
2. I check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372248/launch-sms-application-with-an-intent) post, but it doesn't work!

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372248/launch-sms-application-with-an-intent

Comment: yes, I know, but it doesn't work too

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372248/launch-sms-application-with-an-intent

Comment: @OnkarNene I said, it doesn't work!

Comment: @ D. Wayne: After open the SMS app, it will shows list of message by using your above code. Could we open the detail of a user if I know the incoming number? I am having same issue when read incoming SMS by using default app

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try this, it work for me:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MESSAGING);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This works, other SO threads related to this question has answers with deprecate functions.

Comment: It worked for me because I was looking for view SMS list, not send SMS

Answer (score 8):

Use this:

```
public void composeSmsMessage(String message, String phoneNumber) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"+phoneNumber)); // This ensures only SMS apps respond
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

[Official Docmentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Messaging)

Comment: I get error: `No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND dat=smsto:xxxxxxxxxx }`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

```
try {

     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);     
     intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);    
     intent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
     startActivity(intent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    Log.d("Error" , "Error");
}
```

Comment: Its Working fine

Comment: @Ankesh kumar Jaisansaria  Does it matter what the String is after "...setData(Uri.parse"String:")?  I see many examples using "sms:" and many others using "smsto:"

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
smsIntent.putExtra("address", "12125551212");
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","Body of Message");
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

Answer (score 3):

Below code Perfectly worked for me, Hope it will help other

**This code also works if you want to return to app back**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumber)); // This ensures only SMS apps respond
        intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hey downaload Whozhere app");
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

official doc https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#SendMessage

```
public void composeMmsMessage(String message, Uri attachment) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE);
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + Uri.encode(phoneNumber)));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can used deep linking using intent filter in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
```

intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + Uri.encode(phoneNumber)));
startActivity(intent);

Comment: Hello, please add a comment to explain your answer (and why we should use your instead of already accepted one). Please also add 4 spaces at beginning of each line of code to have it formatted well !

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(intent);
```

it's working

Comment: Can you explain how does the same code works for you. Some details other that just _it's working_ will be useful.