# Open SMS app using Intent from web page

Tags: android, google-chrome, uri-scheme

I know there is a way to open the SMS app on Android directly from a browser.
I need that with Intent URI Scheme and not with "sms:?&".

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9664882/1768413

Comment: @EvgeniIvanov Thanks. But i need the html version for chrome, not the native Android code.

Comment: Ok, i see than maybe this will give you some guidance on how to achive what you really want: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents .The example given is for Zxing, but it shouldn't be too difficult to modify for the sms app.

Comment: @EvgeniIvanov i thought so too, but it didn't work :)